# basic for loop logic when it comes to arrays?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around simple logic because arrays start with 0. I'm going to massivley simplify my issue:

I have an array of size 5. Indexes go as follows [0],[1],[2],[3],[4]. Increment is 2.
I need to check the difference between elements every increment.

```
//So the result I want:
var1 = a[2] - a[0]
var2 = a[4] - a[2].
//My for loop:
incr = 2;
size = 5;
for (x = 0; x + incr < size; x+= incr)
    var[] = a[x + incr] - a[x]
```

This for loops fails at the fact that `a[x + incr]` is going to be out of bounds. How can I stucture this correctly?

Comment: How does it fail? First `x` is 0, and `x + incr < size` is `0 + 2 < 5`, which is true, and `a[2] - a[0]` is calculated. Then `x` is 2, and `x + incr < size` is `2 + 2 < 5`, and `a[4] - a[2]` is calculated. Then `x` is 4, and `x + incr < size` is `4 + 2 < 5`, which is false, and the loop stops. That seems to be what you want. Aside from the loop control, you will want to specify some subscript for `var`, perhaps `var[x/incr+1] = …` (for `var[1]` and `var[2]`) or `var[x/incr] = …` (for `var[0]` and `var[1]`).

Comment: Your loop breaks in case it goes out of bounds

Comment: @woz: By “breaks” do you mean “the loop exits due to the test” or “the loop fails to operate as desired”? And what is “it”? There is no matching antecedent for that pronoun.

Comment: @EricPostpischil first one.

Comment: @woz: Then a clear sentence is “The loop correctly exits when `x + incr` would be out of bounds for the array.”

Comment: Now I'm confused. What do you expect it to do instead of exiting, in your example, when `x = 4`?

Comment: `var[] = a[x + incr] - a[x]` is not legal syntax

Answer (score 2):

It won't be out of bounds. If ever `x + incr` is indeed `>= size`, then the `for` condition would fail and not execute the statement within.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, `size` must be calculated using `len` method or `length` property (or whatever your programming language supports), however, in this case I can see that you specified it manually by giving `size = 5`, so in case actual length of array `a` is smaller than `5` and `x + incr >= 5` it should cause an out bound error

Answer (score 0):

> How can I structure this correctly?

No need to write a loop if you used [std::adjacent_difference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/adjacent_difference):

```
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
   int a[5] = {1,7,9,2,5};
   int b[5];
   std::adjacent_difference(a, a + 5, b);
   for (auto i : b)
     std::cout << i << " ";
}
```

Output:

```
1 6 2 -7 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be using a compiler with fancy extensions that supports random things but `var[] = a[x + incr] - a[x]` this is not valid standard syntax.  Since you didn't explain what actually failed I am assuming that the failure is at this line.  To start, define `var` to be the size and type that you want out.  In this case I assume you want an integer array of size 2 since there are 2 instances to calculate for an array of size 5.

```
int var[2];
```

Then in the array use an index to place values into `var` where they belong, remember to increment your placement.

```
int place_index = 0;
for (x = 0; x + incr < size; x+= incr){
    var[place_index] = a[x + incr] - a[x];
    place_index++;
}
```

Then you can display the results

```
for (x = 0; x < 2; x++)
    std::cout << var[x] << ' ';
```

Given `a[5] = {0,1,2,3,4}`, this prints `2 2`.  Given `a[5] = {0,2,4,6,8}`, this prints `4 4`.  Given `a[5] = {0, 2, 8, 32, 128}`, this prints `8 120`.

There are other ways to solve this using iterators, transforms, standard library, etc.